# AspectJ: avoid execution of enumeration

Tags: java, enums, aspectj

I have a `method` annotated with this:

```
@Around("execution(* it.foo.bar.Flow.*(..))")
public Object profile(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {...}
```

In the `Flow class` I have a simple `switch` on an `enumeration type`. When I ran on that line the `profile method` above is called. This is the `pjp object` I have:

```
execution(int[] it.foo.bar.Flow.$SWITCH_TABLE$it$foo$bar$dataobjects$RequestType())
```

`RequestType` is the `enum`.
I'd like to avoid `profile method` being invoked when the `enum` is encountered, so I tried with a couple of execution expression, but it didn't work, not even with the following one in addition to the one above:

```
&& !(execution(int[]     it.foo.bar.Flow.$SWITCH_TABLE$it$foo$bar$dataobjects$RequestType()))
```

Is it possible to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Can you please show a snippet of Flow class which includes the switch.

Comment: @Biju imagine it's not really anything more than `switch(enumType) { case...}` and of course some other not so relevant code.

Comment: Yes, true Carlo, but switch is inside a method of Flow class right, so I am wondering how is switch getting woven at all, it should be the methods of Flow that should get woven

Comment: @Biju yes, that's what I'd like to understand too. Maybe I should ask this question to an AspectJ developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to weave a class at a finer grained level than a method. You could extract out the functionality of that handles the `RequestType` `enum` into a separate method and adjust your pointcut expression to avoid that:

```
@Around("execution(* it.foo.bar.Flow.*(..)) && !execution(* it.foo.bar.Flow.handleRequestType(..))")
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I know this is another question, but can you point me to the reason that why this happens with enumeration? I mean, is a switch statement compiled as some sort of method? I'd like to understand the "internals" of the matter.

Comment: Also, knowing this, I'll stick with my workaround, since I don't wanna add a pointcut expression for each and every method where I use a switch. That take out the simple beauty of weaving code, imho.

Comment: No, no new methods are created for the `switch` statement.